# Getting AccessDenied error using S3 pre-signed POST

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 via a pre-signed POST, and getting a 403 AccessDenied error when I try to use the generated POST details.

I'm generating the pre-signed POST via a Lambda function. The function has an attached policy that gives it write permissions on the bucket:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion",
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
    "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
    "s3:DeleteObject"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
],
```

The bucket is currently public ("Block all public access" is OFF) and it has no bucket policy attached. It has a CORS policy allowing GET and POST from anywhere:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

The Lambda function calls the boto3 function [generate_presigned_post()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post):

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
fields = {
    "acl": "private",
}
conditions = [
    {"acl": "private"},
]
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket='my-bucket',
    Key="${filename}",
    Fields=fields,
    Conditions=conditions)
```

and returns a valid-looking response:

```
{
    "url": "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    "fields": {
        "acl": "private",
        "key": "${filename}",
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "**********",
        "x-amz-security-token": "**********",
        "policy":"**********",
        "signature": "**********"
    }
}
```

I then use the response in my local Postman to construct a multipart form upload, passing the file as the "file" parameter:

[image: Postman upload fields]

And I get an AccessDenied response.

What am I overlooking? What critical step have I missed? Am I constructing the POST request correctly in Postman? Does the pre-signed POST require further configuration? How can I debug it?

EDIT:

Lambda function now has additional policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below permissions to allow multi part uploads

```
s3:ListMultipartUploadParts
s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
s3:AbortMultipartUpload
```

Also, ensure you add the same region in AWS Signature as the creds were created, snapshot below

[image: AWS Signature]

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid. The Lambda function has the additional policy statement attached:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

but I'm still getting the same AccessDenied error on upload.

Comment: @Wintermute Can you check the region with which signed url is generated, check in credentials or config file. Use the same region in postman AWS Signature -> advanced section

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by AWS Signature -> advanced section? I've added an explicit region in the Lambda function: s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1') (that's the region that the Lambda function is defined in) but I'm not sure how to add the region to the signature? It's just a plain text string, e.g. "xR9qwgWOwRHGePPJanAbMjEMrAA=".

Comment: @Wintermute Updated answer with pic for AWS signature

Comment: Oh God. I'm SO sorry. I had attached the permissions policy to the wrong function. If it's any consolation, your advice about adding the additional permissions for multipart uploads was much appreciated, and your note above about the signature helped me realise that I should explicitly state the signature version, e.g. s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')). However, I sincerely apologise for wasting your time on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @Wintermute No worries at all !! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, this was a wild goose chase. I'd attached the permissions policy to the wrong function.